# Nice Regex routes for a PHP MVC router?

Tags: regex, model-view-controller, router

I'm building a web app using MVC architecture in PHP, and one of the first components I am building is the router. Currently, it works like this:

```
// Cleans the URI
SimpleRouter::init(); 

// Adds a new URI matching rule
SimpleRouter::add_route( '\/app\-admin\/products\/edit\/([0-9]+)\/', 'MyFunc' );
```

I want my code to look like this though, to make it a bit more readable/easier to remember

```
// Adds a new URI matching rule
SimpleRouter::add_route( '/app-admin/products/edit/([0-9]+)/', 'MyFunc' );
```

Any ideas how I might implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to escape the dash.

As for the slash, if you start and end your regex with something else (any character, such as #, or |) you don't need to escape the slash either.

P.S.: Don't use static access.. otherwise what's the point of making it OOP? How do I subclass it, etc..

Comment: For this specific scenario there is absolutely no reason I'd have to subclass the router, but I'll make it an object anyways. Thanks for the other tip, I always though regex had to start and end with /